# adobe air application with folder

Tags: flash, air

I will like ask that if I could create aplication that in the root of the application have a xml file and a folder with images.

I will like that create a install with all. It is posible? incorporate file that it is not a reference inside fla file.

Thank you

Comment: If you publish with Flash IDE: on the AIR publish screen there's a tab with included files, by default there is main SWF and XML descriptor, but you are free to add more files there. FlashDevelop puts everything in the ./bin folder into the package by default.

Comment: Depending on your situation... Also you could just `embed` the XML & images (or better, one zip of all images). Now all these bytes exist within the program so either use them from here or else on each run it checks if the xml & image folder exists... If yes, continue as usual -- or else --  if not, then just create folder by AS3 code & write the embedded bytes as files within app's install folder. Like I said it depends on what situation/limitations you've experienced while making your app...